# JSON file comparison shell - Find differences

Tags: json, shell, scripting

I am looking for some command or json iterator for shell script which will allow to compare to JSON files and print the only the items which has changed. Both Json files will be in Same exact format except values may differ.

Example sample_one.json :

{

"Data1": {
    "Green": "1",
    "Blue": "2"
  },
  "Data2": {
    "Flag": 0,
    "Priority": 2
  }
}

Example sample_two.json :

{

"Data1": {
    "Green": "4",
    "Blue": "2"
  },
  "Data2": {
    "Flag": 5,
    "Priority": 2
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can assume the order of the keys is fixed as well, you can simply `diff` the output of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
diff <(jq '.' sample_one.son) <(jq '.' sample_two.son)
```

`jq` here is being used to pretty-print the JSON so that a line-oriented diff makes sense. It might be possible to script something using `jq` alone.